# c# Programm using Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo info) does not work

Tags: c#, openvpn

I tried to open a OpenVPN connection using a small c# program.
Below is the code I used.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process rs = new Process();
    var netCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "PWD", "Domain");
    System.Environment.CurrentDirectory = ".\\";
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "c:\\programme\\openvpn\\bin\\openvpn.exe",
        Arguments = "--config c:\\programme\\openvpn\\config\\NAS-Name.ovpn",
        UserName = netCredential.UserName,
        Domain = netCredential.Domain,
        Password = netCredential.SecurePassword,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        //RedirectStandardError = true,
        //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        //CreateNoWindow = true,
        WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName("c:\\programme\\openvpn\\bin\\openvpn.exe")
    };
    var p = Process.Start(info);
}
```

This code does work, but only on the computer were I compiled it.
On our server (Win server 2019) I get the error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:System cant find file
> at System.Diagnostics.ProcessWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
> at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
> at ConnectOpenVPN.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\User\path\to\Program.cs:Zeile 43

I don´t understand where the last line of the error message comes from.

Comment: It is probably located in "c:\\program files", not "c:\\programme"

Comment: The error message seems quite clear though - it can't see the file. adjust the path so it can find the executable on the server

Comment: I suggest you use [Environment.SpecialFolder Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1) like `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles))`. And then `Path.Combine` to add the openvpn part.

Comment: ^^ I'd also check the existence of .exe and config file before using them. ( `if (File.Exists(pathToFile)) ... ` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using a german windows or similar.

Beware that the display value of file pathes in windows explorer does not reflect the real path, see picture.

```
C:\Programme -> C:\Program Files
```

You can reveal the real path by clicking in the address bar.

[image: displayed path vs real path]

try:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process rs = new Process();
        var netCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("User", "PWD", "Domain");
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = ".\\";
        var vpnConfigPath = Path.Combine(
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
           "openvpn", "config", "NAS-Name.ovpn");
        var vpnPath = Path.Combine(
           Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles),
           @"openvpn","bin","openvpn.exe");
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = vpnPath,
            Arguments = $"--config \"{vpnConfigPath}\"",
            UserName = netCredential.UserName,
            Domain = netCredential.Domain,
            Password = netCredential.SecurePassword,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            //RedirectStandardError = true,
            //RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            //CreateNoWindow = true,
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(vpnPath)
        };
        var p = Process.Start(info);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look into `Environment.SpecialFolder` enum and `Environment.GetFolderPath`. You'll quickly see why it's a good idea to use them.